# Future method with higher limits

Tags: apex

Has `@Future` method with higher `limits` been removed from **Spring 19** release? I'm asking it because [Future Methods with Higher Limits (Pilot)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enhanced_future_overview.htm) page has been removed from Apex Developer Guide.

Comment: Might be a mistake from SF Docs team.. Official guide still mentions them here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You're right--there's a bug. That pilot should not be mentioned in the docs anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature has been deprecated for a number of years, and the pilot was terminated a long time ago. You will not be able to use the higher limits in new code.